# What are geodesics on a cylinder?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, geodesic

How would you go about proving where geodesics occur on a cylinder. I know that the parametrisation of a cylinder is (cos, sinv, u)but not sure how to go on from here?

Answer (score 7):

Cylinders (as usually embedded in Euclidean space) are flat. So you can determine the geodesics simply by uncurling the cylinder into a flat rectangle.

e.g. the $r=r_0$ cylinder in cylindrical $(r,\theta,z)$ coordinates maps to Cartesian $(x,y)$ coordinates on the plane by $(x,y) = (r_0 \theta, z)$.

Comment: How would you do this explicitly stating the parametrisation?